# How to code for React Native apps using Sublime

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sublimetext3

I am new to React Native. I could not find any set up guide to code for React Native apps using Sublime. How can I create a React Native project in Sublime?

I installed these components from [tutorial](http://www.nitinh.com/2015/02/setting-sublime-text-react-jsx-development/) and followed [these guides](http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2015/10/react-native-android-application-development-in-windows.html/), but when I tried to build from sublime, nothing has happened.

Any one mind to enlighten me? I know this is not a right place to ask but I could not think of any others and I am seriously stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly run from **sublime**. Sublime is a **TextEditor** that you can use to change your react-native code. But to run the application you need to run the respective project in their respective IDEs. For an example, if you want to run it for iOS, you need to open your project in Xcode and run for the first time. Once it's launched by **Xcode** and simulator, then you can start coding in **react-native** in Sublime text editor and `Command+R` to reflect those changes here.

You can see `index.ios.js` file which is entry point for iOS code and you can create `index.android.js` file which becomes entry point for android. In React native there are **two ways to run platform specific code** one is by naming the files like (x.andoid.js or x.ios.js). Here the middle one tells which platform this file has to run on. Example, when you have two files x.android.js and x.ios.js when you run the code on the Android device the code in x.android.js, will be called and when you run it on iPhone x.ios.js will be called. While calling you will just call with name index.js. That's it. If you don't want to distinguish between two platforms and run the same code just you need to name it as index.js file

**Answering another question of yours:**

That **android folder** have native Android code inside. Same for iOS. All your code that cross platform you need to write in js files. It will start with index.js file by default

Comment: I see I see. I misunderstood it as I used to do android apps using Android Studio and I thought I can just run from the same platform. I created a demo project using 'react-native init ReactNativeAndroidDemo' from the link in the question. From Sublime, I saw two sub-folders namely android and ios. Does that means that whichever I wrote in android will be applied to ios as well?

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. which file should I be working on it in order to have a cross-platform apps

Comment: That android folder have native android code inside. Same for iOS. All your code that cross platform you need to write in js files. It will start with index.js file by default

Comment: You can see index.ios.js file which is entry point for iOS code and you can create index.android.js file which becomes entry point for android. If you don't want to distinguish between two platforms and run the same code just you need to name it as index.js file

Comment: I see I see, thanks so much! So whichever new page/activity I creating, the js file should be located below the index.js, am I right? Basically I can just ignore all the native code files as react native could help me compile automatically according to the platforms, am I right?

Comment: Even you can add some folder to place your js files instead of below the index.js. It's just recommended but not compulsory to run the application. Structuring your js files is up to you. Best practices will always help you in future. All the best.

Comment: Hey sorry but let's say I deployed the code onto my Android device using Expo, how can I actually debug it? Because I don't see any console around.

Comment: Use Command+D on Simulator to get debugging options. From that select 'Debug remotely'. You can't see the console in Xcode. Instead you need to check on Chrome/browser console

Comment: Let's say I am using windows and deploying onto actual Android device rather than simulator. How can I actually debug it?

Comment: tap R twice on Android emulators.

Comment: Hey sorry let me make this clear. So in order to debug the app regardless of whether it is Android or iOS, I have to deploy it onto emulators then remotely control it from the actual device? Is that the only way? Because I got problem installing genymotion emulator from Expo.

Comment: Actually, we do it with simulator/emulator. If in case you are having a problem these, you can debug from device also. Expo will launch your app on device right. Just Shaking of the device should result in same menu selection where you can select Debug remotely option(Try Shacking device. I didn't try).

Comment: Check this out. It might be helpful. https://differential.com/insights/intro-to-debugging-react-native-ios-and-android/

Comment: I see I see. Thanks so much! I didn't know that by shaking the device could enable debug mode for both Android and iOS.

Comment: @EmmaHannah I think you can upvote comments and highlight which really useful for some other people.  ;-)